# Relative speed of gaussian process classification

Tags: gaussian-process, model-evaluation

I used gaussian process classification implemented in Matlab gpml toolbox and also in R kernlab. For my problem - 600*14 matrix with two classes - it trains order of magnitude slower than other classifiers. Gauss. process is taking hours to finish what SVM/naive bayes/random forest does within minutes.

Is this expected behavior of the classifier, or is there some other reason for such a poor speed? (e.g. scale of the data, slow implementation, etc.)

Comment: naive GP classification is $O(N^3)$ where $N$ is the number of samples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPML generally tunes the hyper-parameters as well as fitting the model, which takes quite a while.  This ought to be done for SVMs as well for a like-for-like comparison (SVMs can take a very long time to train depending on the hyper-parameter values).  If you are using the minimize function, that probably explains the difference.